# Why does my bubble sort ignore the last variable?c++

Tags: c++, sorting, variables

For some reason whenever I select random variables for my code I get one number going to the end of an ascending bubble sort.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int a, b, c, d, e, hold;

    cout << "Input 5 integers for sorting, press enter after each number.\n";
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)//runs the sequence 5 times to match the number of variables.
    {
        hold = a;
        if (b < hold) 
           {
                 hold = b;
                 b = a;
                 a = hold;
            }
        if (c < hold) 
           {
                 hold = c;
                 c = b;
                 b = hold;
           }
        if (d < hold) 
           {
                 hold = d;
                 d = c;
                 c = hold;
           }
        if (e < hold) 
           {
                 hold = e;
                 e = d;
                 d = hold;
           }

        cout << "The smallest number was " << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << " " << e << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with the numbers 98, 45, 65, 12, and 32, my final two results are 12, 45, 98, 65, 32.

Edit: I don't know what I did when copying my code into the post but it was very not what I was seeing in my compiler. Sorry for messing that up.

Comment: Please show respect to the community by formatting your code.

Comment: A good start would be to format your code to make it readable. In other words, please use some indentation, your code is completely unreadable now.

Comment: As for your problem, you don't need a loop or temporary variables to sort five distinct separate variables. You might need it if you have an arbitrarily sized array. All you need now is a set of `if` statements. Can easily be done in a function that checks and swaps two values.

Comment: A couple of other tips: Work it all out on *paper* first, before you code. Then if the code doesn't work, use a debugger to step through the code line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your bubble sort is in your comparisons after the swaps.
After comparing b < hold, and swapping, your hold contains the previous number value thus you are comparing using the wrong number.
In your case, there is no point using hold for comparison, instead just compare b < a, c < b and so on.

```
    if (b < a) {
        hold = b;
        b = a;
        a = hold;
    }
    if (c < b) {
        hold = c;
        c = b;
        b = hold;
    }
    if (d < c) {
        hold = d;
        d = c;
        c = hold;
    }
    if (e < d) {
        hold = e;
        e = d;
        d = hold;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, after reading the others I came up with something very similar.

I actually started that based on my teachers notes to find the largest number alone, but I see where I went wrong.

Comment: @Terrence Consider just using `std::swap`.

Comment: @remyabel Yes, thanks. The main problem the questioner had was in comparing the wrong number. Although swapping is not the cause of his problems, there are definitely better ways of coding this example. Like using 2 'for' loops can allow for a reduced number of comparison.